# General OpenVPN + DNS Strategy

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, bind

I'm creating a virtual private cloud as a development environment.  Right now there is just a single server running OpenVPN, BIND and Subversion at IP 10.0.0.100.

If I pass along *push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.100"*, then clients can resolve the cloud resources by name (svn.example.dev = 10.0.0.100), but then they can't resolve local DNS names on their own network (e.g. desktop1.example.local).

How can I "add" instead of "replace" dns servers for clients?  Or am I now going about this all wrong and I should have a single DNS server that they both access?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a forwarding resolver *on each client machine*, configured to "forward" queries for `.dev` to `10.0.0.100` and all other queries to the `.local` server.

[Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) is quite lightweight, and has easy configuration for forwarding like this.

Possibly the only hard part is hooking into OpenVPN to only enable that forwarding only when the tunnel is up, if required.